# Deep copy of a pointer function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class (myClass) that has a pointer to function as private member like this:

```
void (gi::myClass::*ptrFunction) (int  , int  , vector<int> & , vector<int> & , vector<int> &);
```

When you create at runtime (with new) a object (a *myClass ptrObject) of myClass this pointer is inizialited in the constructor with the address of a function.
After with the same object created above I call another function.
In this function I must create a deep copy of the calling object:

```
gi::myClass *ptrObject2 = new myClass(....);
```

Above I call a constructor that do the copy but it don't initialize the member *ptrFunction of *ptrObject2
My question is:
How do I do a deep copy of the pointer function from the *ptrObject to ptrObject2?
(My compiler is C++11)

Comment: Are you asking how to copy a function pointer?

Comment: Pointer to member function has no difference between 'deep copy' and 'shallow copy' ... there is no associated object, it's basically just an offset

Comment: Namely  can I do ptrObject2->ptrFunction = ptrObject->ptrFunction ? @M.M

Comment: Yes I must copy a function pointer (pointer member of  ptrObject  to a pointer member of ptrObject2) @Ben

Answer (score 3):

There is no *deep-copy* of a function pointer. You are not copying any data, just a reference into the v-table. As such:

```
ptrObject2->ptrFunction = ptrObject->ptrFunction
```

Is fine.

Comment: Clear. Thanks so much